# Get id of Buttons using php once clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I have 4 buttons,and also an exportexcel button.I want to set the excel filename.If i clicked getToday button, i want to set the today date to the excel.

```
<div class="span3 btns_state">
    <div data-toggle="buttons-radio" id="toggleButton" class="btn-group clearfix sepH_a">
        <button type="button" name="getTday" id="getToday" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom active" data-original-title="<?php echo $today;?>"onclick = "show()">Today</button>
        <button type="button" name="getWeek" id="getWeek" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom" data-original-title="<?php echo $this_week;?>"onclick = "show()">This Week</button>
        <button type="button" name="getMonth" id="getMonth" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom" data-original-title="<?php echo $this_month;?>"onclick = "show()">This Month</button>
        <button type="button" name="getPreMonth" id="getpremon"class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom" data-original-title="<?php echo $previous_month;?>"onclick = "show()">Last Month</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My php code to get the dates.

```
 $str = $_GET['getTday'];
 if($str == 'getToday')
 {
   $var=$today; 
 }
 else
 {
   $var=$this_week;
 }
```

I want to retrieve the dates corresponding to the button i clicked,but only else part is working.
Here is the excel export.

```
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), Report-<?php echo $var?>.xlsx");
```

Comment: make button type="submit"

Comment: The `id` attribute is a client-side property of the DOM. Use the `name` attribute instead.

Comment: id of buttons cannot be posted directly using php, use javascript instead, to get the id of element clicked and post it to other page using GET method. Other way to do is to make these buttons links and pass the ids as GET value parameter ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query string to pass the value of clicked button

refer the "Today" button below.

You can set the value of variable "$var" to your execel or anything.

[Note:I done in the same page,create "test.php" and paste the following code and try,it will works well]

Thank You.

```
<?php 
 //Assume Variables $today and $this_week like below
 $today = date('Y-m-d');
 $this_week = "This week";
 $var = "";
 if(isset($_GET['getTday'])):
 $str = $_GET['getTday'];
    if($str == 'getToday')
    {
      $var=$today; 
    }
    else
    {
     $var=$this_week;
    }

 endif;
 echo $var;
?>
<div class="span3 btns_state">
        <div data-toggle="buttons-radio" id="toggleButton" class="btn-group clearfix sepH_a"  >
            <button type="button" name="getTday" id="getToday" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom active" data-original-title="<?php echo $today;?>"onclick = "show('getToday')">Today</button>
            <button type="button" name="getWeek" id="getWeek" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom" data-original-title="<?php echo $this_week;?>"onclick = "show()">This Week</button>
            <button type="button" name="getMonth" id="getMonth" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom" data-original-title="<?php echo $this_month;?>"onclick = "show()">This Month</button>
            <button type="button" name="getPreMonth" id="getpremon"class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom" data-original-title="<?php echo $previous_month;?>"onclick = "show()">Last Month</button>

        </div>
      </div>
<script>
function show(val)
{
if(val == 'getToday')
{
    location.href = "test.php?getTday=getToday";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery click event to perform your action. You have to remove all click event inside html

```
 $(".btn.btn-info.rep_data.tip-bottom").click(function(){
        var name=$(this).attr("name");
// you can get what ever it is 
// this.id;
// this.value

        });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f88h/4/)

NOTE: Dont write event in html it is not good practis

Answer (score 0):

Make button type `submit` with form tag

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" name="getTday">
     and so on...
</form>
```

Then you will get in php like `$_GET['getTday']` this will get `name` attr of field so keep id and name same

else you need to use jquery/js to get id of button

Answer (score 0):

add `value` attribute in your button like this `value="getToday"`.

You can get this in php file.

**Example**

```
<button type="button" name="getTday" id="getToday" value="getToday" class="btn btn-info rep_data tip-bottom active" data-original-title="<?php echo $today;?>"onclick = "show()">Today</button>
```